# Why is this VBA giving me a 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a few different renditions here are some I THINK should work:

```
Sheets(Sheet1.Name).Range("Q2").Value = "=IF($H2="""","""",IF($L2=""Successful"",0,IF($O2="""",""Error"",!$O2)))"

Sheets(Sheet1.Name).Range("Q2").Formula = "=IF($H2="""","""",IF($L2=""Successful"",0,IF($O2="""",""Error"",!$O2)))"

Sheets(Sheet1.Name).[Q2].Formula = "=IF($H2="""","""",IF($L2=""Successful"",0,IF($O2="""",""Error"",!$O2)))"

Dim Data As Worksheet
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets1.Name)
Data. (all of the above after the sheets part)
```

No matter what I do this gives a 1004 error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove all the quotes and use chr(34) for when you need quotes in the string.  That is very hard to read.  You should also point out which line is giving the error.

Comment: `Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets1.Name)` worries me - elsewhere you use a worksheet with a codename of `Sheet1`, but in this statement you are using a sheet with a codename of `Sheets1` - is that a typo?  And, FWIW, assuming the sheet with the codename of `Sheet1` is in the `ActiveWorkbook`, then `Sheets(Sheet1.Name).` is identical to `Sheet1.`.

Comment: No that is just another way I tried to get the formula to work.  These are multiple ways I tried to get it to work.

Comment: Unless you have two sheets, one with a codename of `Sheets1` and one with a codename of `Sheet1`, one of those methods would have given you an Object required error.  (Your 1004 error is, as has been answered, due to the stray `!`, but I'm just trying to pick up other issues so that you don't have to post new questions once you remove the `!`.)

Comment: I am using the actual sheet names in the code.  I just changed it to try and figure out what was going on with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the "!" before "$O2".

Comment: wow; I can't even believe that I read that line 100 times and didn't notice that.  Now It is giving 91; I am thinking that is due to the $